# Launch browser using puppeteer on docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

I am trying to launch the browser using **puppeteer** on **docker** container.

However, when I am trying load the browser by hitting the API, I am seeing the following error
[image]

`localhost:3000` is my client running locally. I am not sure if docker can access this address. I am thinking maybe this could be the reason for the connection failure. Please correct me if I am wrong.

When I try the above scenario without docker, it is working fine, I am able to see the puppeteer opening chromium browsers and show the page. To make it work on the docker container, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The `localhost` on your host, where your application running on port 3000 is, is in a different namespace compared to the `localhost` for your puppeteer instance running in docker.

To fix this, you can either:

- Make them be in the same namespace (Host Mode)
- Create a bridge between them (Bridge Mode)

### Host Mode

This puts your container in the same network namespace as the host. `localhost` will refer to the same thing inside and outside the container. Add `--net-host` to your `docker run` command

### Bridge Mode

You can form a bridge between the container and host, by adding `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to the `docker run` command, and changing puppeteer to use `host.docker.internal:3000`